# XSL transform group elements thats follow

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Here is what I have in XML:

```
      <par level="4">Hi </par>
      <par level="4">There!</par>
      <par level="12">abcd :</par>
      <par level="12">efgh .</par>
      <par level="4">azert</par>
      <par level="4">yuio</par>
      <par level="4">p</par>
      <par level="4">)</par>
```

When I read PAR elements I want to concat content inside the same DIV until the LEVEL attribute is still the same as previous one. But if the LEVEL changes I need to create a new DIV. The content order doesn't have to change, so the first "level 4" PAR doesn't have to be merged with second one.  I've seen similar problems except for the last point I mentioned.

So here is what I want after the xsl transform of the above sample: (XSLT 1.0)

```
      <div class="level4">
        Hi there!
      </div>
      <div class="level12">
        abcd :efgh .
      </div>          
      <div class="level4">
        azertyuiop)
      </div>
```

I already have a template xsl:template match="par"> with a lot of code inside.
What could you suggest to achieve this?

Comment: are these suppose to be level14?  <par level="4">azert</par>
      <par level="4">yuio</par>
      <par level="4">p</par>
      <par level="4">)</par>

Comment: @james31rock : no there are 2 "level 4" blocks. and they don't have to be grouped inside the same div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**XML Input** (modified to be well-formed)

```
<doc>
    <par level="4">Hi </par>
    <par level="4">There!</par>
    <par level="12">abcd :</par>
    <par level="12">efgh .</par>
    <par level="4">azert</par>
    <par level="4">yuio</par>
    <par level="4">p</par>
    <par level="4">)</par>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par[not(@level = preceding-sibling::par[1]/@level)]">
        <div class="level{@level}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>      
            <xsl:apply-templates select="(following-sibling::par[1])[@level=@level]" mode="dump"/>      
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par[preceding-sibling::par[1]/@level=@level]"/>

    <xsl:template match="par" mode="dump">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::par[1]/@level = @level">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::par[1]" mode="dump"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <div class="level4">Hi There!</div>
   <div class="level12">abcd :efgh .</div>
   <div class="level4">azertyuiop)</div>
</doc>
```